# Django Migrations, adding a field to an existent model

Tags: django-models

I'm working with DJANGO.
I´m trying to add a column on my table 'ano_letivo', a table of my database. But I'm having difficulties on adding it.

//Original class

```
class ano_letivo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ano_letivo = models.CharField(db_column='ano_letivo', max_length=255)
    dia_inicio = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    dia_fim = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ativo = models.CharField(db_column='ativo', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ano_letivo'
```

//My file with the added field

```
class ano_letivo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ano_letivo = models.CharField(db_column='ano_letivo', max_length=255)
    dia_inicio = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    dia_fim = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ativo = models.CharField(db_column='ativo', max_length=10)
    yau = models.CharField(db_column='yau', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ano_letivo'
```

Commands made:

python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'anoletivo':
anoletivo\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model ano_letivo

python manage.py migrate
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MariaDB Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
HINT: MariaDB's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MariaDB, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, anoletivo, auth, contenttypes, importacoes, main, pedidos, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying anoletivo.0001_initial... OK
Applying importacoes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
res = self._query(query)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
db.query(q)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'curso' already exists")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Documentos\Universidade\3Ano2Semestre\LES_2324\LES_PROJETO\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Documentos\Universidade\3Ano2Semestre\LES_2324\LES_PROJETO\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 349, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 130, in apply
operation.database_forwards(
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
schema_editor.create_model(model)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 447, in create_model
self.execute(sql, params or None)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 199, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
res = self._query(query)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
db.query(q)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'curso' already exists")

Comment: Did you remove a migration file?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).